# Changing the first graph line with a standard color (black) in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, aes

In line with the question posted in this link [change line color in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323202/change-line-color-in-ggplot/68589565#68589565)

How can I make group1 with black color and the rest multicolor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using `scale_color_identity` would help -

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dftt %>%
  mutate(color = sample(colors(), n_distinct(group))[group], 
         color = replace(color, group == 1, 'black')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=values, group=color, color=color)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_color_identity(guide = "legend", labels = unique(dftt$group))
```

**data**

Using data from the linked post -

```
dftt <- data.frame(values = runif(11*4,0,1),
                 col = c(rep(2,4),
                         rep(1,4),
                         rep(5,9*4)),
                 x= rep(1:4, 11*4),
                 group=rep(factor(1:11), each=4)
                 )
```